# Facebook API for getting all the wall posts

Tags: facebook, api

Is there any facebook API to get all the wall post of a particular user

or

a limited (say 10) number of wall posts

Comment: you need to give a bit of detail about what technology you are integrating with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is the Facebook Graph API for querying this data http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ but I have no idea from your question what technology you want to integrate with